# Linearly Dependent Set Necessary if and only if Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Show that a set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots , v_l\}$ in a vector space $V$ is linearly dependent if and only if
$v_1 = 0$ or there is $2 \le j \le l$ such that $v_j$ is a linear combination of the vectors $v_1,\ldots , v_{j−1}$.

The “$\Leftarrow$” direction is easy since if $v_1=0$, then $c_1$ can be anything making it linearly dependent or if $v_j$ is a linear combination of the vectors $v_1,\ldots , v_{j−1}$., then by definition it is linearly dependent.

However, the “$\Rightarrow$” direction is confusing me; I am thinking i split it into two cases: 1) $v_1=0$, then we are done 2) $v_1 \ne 0$, to which we have to show some $v_j$ is a linear combination of its previous vectors, which i cannot figure out.

In addition, why is it just $v_1=0$ but not $v_i=0$ for any $i$, would that not make more sense? Maybe I do not understand because I am missing a crucial step in the proof here.

Comment: Take $j=\text{max} \{i\in \{1,…,l\} \mid c_i\neq 0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If the set is linearly dependent, there exist constants $c_1, \ldots, c_l$ not all zero such that
$$c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_l v_l = 0.$$

- If $c_l \ne 0$, then it satisfies the claim with $j=l$.
- Else, if $c_l = 0$ and $c_{l-1} \ne 0$, then it satisfies the claim with $j = l-1$.
- $\cdots$
- Else, if $c_l = \cdots = c_3 = 0$ and $c_2 \ne 0$, then it satisfies the claim with $j=2$.
- Else, $c_l = \cdots = c_2 = 0$. But then the equation yields $c_1 v_1 = 0$. Since $c_1 \ne 0$ by assumption, we must have $v_1 = 0$.

Comment: good proof (+1).

Comment: thank you but how does it satisfy the claim with =−1? We can divide the whole equation by $c_{l-1}$ to obtain an expression for$ v_{l-1}$ but that would include $v_l$ in that expression as well and the question says linear combination of $ v_1,...,v_{l-2}$ .

Comment: @jamesblack It won't include $v_l$ in the expression because $c_l=0$.